# Typescript arbitrary class mixins function

Tags: typescript, mixins

In the example bellow I try to define function ***classMixin*** which will take arbitrary class and return a new class which extends this arbitrary class. But I get an error stating "*type 'T' is not a constructor function type.*"

How to define a function in Typescript for creating at run-time class mixins?

```
class A
{
    name: string;
}

function classMixin<T extends new()=>any>(baseclass: T)
{
    return class extends baseclass
    {
        age: number;
    }
}

let c = classMixin(A);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixins as defined in the [PR] that introduces them are very particular about the constraint on the constructor. It should be `T extends new(...a: any[])=>any`. The behavior will be that the constructor parameters will be preserved by the mixin which is probably what you want:

```
class A
{
    name: string;
}

function classMixin<T extends new(...a: any[])=>any>(baseclass: T)
{
    return class extends baseclass
    {
        age: number;
    }
}

let c = classMixin(A);
let cc = new c();
```

Comment: Simply great :)! Now immediately the next question arrives is it possible to create sort of run-time multiple inheritance. Pseudo code will look like this:

classesMixin(class:A, class:B) // will return class C extends both A,B if we assume there is no collusion in method and property names and return types.

Comment: @Hivaga  you can use multiple mixins ie `mixin1(mixin2(className))`. Multiple inheritance is not supported, but you can probably perform 'type surgery' and get the effect you want that is `classesMixin(classA, classB)` to return a new class with the instance type `classA & classB` but that is a whole other can of worms I can't answer in the comments (and I think I might have answered in the past something similar but with almost 2k answers its impossible to find anything)